# How to implement custom search with input fields?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, search, meta-query

I want to implement a search form like this: [Loan Form](http://money.gocompare.com/loans)

In my theme I have a custom post type called Data with the Year and Money custom fields.

I googled a lot but can't find a way to submit the user inputs to a place from where I can use `WP_Query` to populate the search result.

So, how to take user input from a form and use it to create a result page in WordPress?

And also please someone explain how the WordPress `?s=` query works.

Answer (score 1):

Creating custom search is not the easiest of tasks for beginners. You will need templates `search.php` and `searchform.php` - [View Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page). You can then edit `searchform.php` and add any fields you need. When the user submits the form it will also add any extra fields you have  - so your search url may look something like this `/?s=1000&num=5&type=years` (using the Loan Form example given in the question).

Once you have your form set up and submitting correctly you can use a hook such as `pre_get_posts` - [View Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) combined with some [Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to test `if is_search()` then you can grab your extra inputs: `$_GET['num'] $_GET['type']` and modify your query based on the values given.

That's the gist of it anyway.